# Book about a boy who crash lands on an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm pretty sure the book is young adult and I listened to the audiobook version probably in 2021. The book is about a boy who's spaceship crash lands on an alien planet and he has to survive on it.

The ships crashes into water but it's not deep enough where it submerges the ship. He starts off by living in his ship and I think he is trying to repair it. During that time I'm pretty sure he hears these really loud noises coming from outside.

Eventually a storm begins and it creates waves that start crashing into the ship and destroys it further. He then has to gather all the supplies and food he can and escape the ship.

One of the nights he sets up camp at I think he can see or hear creatures lurking in the trees near his camp.

Throughout the story there are flashbacks of his life on earth.

There is this strange entity I think it's hidden in shadows that follows the boy. I think it communicates with him telepathically (not 100% sure)

At a certain part in his journey he gets attacked by creatures they were either like wolves or boars.

One point he gets an infected wound and has to burn the infection with fire. I think it's from some type of poisonous bee creature?

I know it's very vague but hopefully someone knows. Thank you!

Comment: In roughly which year did you listen to this?

Comment: It sounds like _Have Spacesuit Will Travel_ by Heinlein, where the protagonist crashlands on Pluto.

Comment: I think I listened to it in 2021. Maybe 2022 at the latest.

Comment: Also it's not Have Spacesuit Will Travel unfortunately :( thank you though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure the book’s name is [“Sovereign” by Jeff Hirsch](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/43807721). It is only on audible though.

> Micah Cole has been in deep space for four years now. While his parents chase their obsession with finding intelligent life deeper and deeper into the universe, Micah can’t help but dream of the friends he’s left behind and counts the days until the family returns to Earth. When a devastating meteor shower nearly destroys the Coles’s ship, Micah is separated from his family and stranded alone on Sovereign—a vast planet of raging rivers and towering forests. If Micah ever wants to see his family or his home again, he’ll have to learn how to survive on this hostile alien world. Armed with only his wits and determination, he’ll have to battle the elements, his own deepest fears, and a strange presence that might just hold the key to his parents’ obsession—and be his ticket back home.